# Transpose the rows and columns in a csv file efficiently in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, transpose

Trying to transpose the rows and columns. Is there a better way to do this?
Also without having to create an additional file and delete it later on.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(output), "1" + ".csv"));
                int rowno = 0;
                string[] csvValues = null;
                string[] headerNames = null;
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                   string csvRowData = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
                   csvValues = csvRowData.Split(';');
                   if (rowno == 0)
                    {
                        headerNames = csvValues;
                       rowno++;
                    }
                  else
                 {
                     for (int j = 0; j < csvValues.Length; j++)
                     {

                        string Column2 = csvValues[j];

                        for (int i = j; i < csvValues.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string Column1 = headerNames[i];

                            string csvtranspose = string.Join(";", Column1, Column2,
```

Environment.NewLine);

```
                            using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(output, true))
                            {
                                wr.Write(csvtranspose);

                            }

                            break;
                        }
                        if (j == 6)
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
            sr.Dispose();
            File.Delete(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(output), "1" + ".csv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the CSVHelper library for these kinds of things.
I put them into a datatable then manipulate them once that's finished.

```
using CSVHelper;
..
..
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    // Do any configuration to `CsvReader` before creating CsvDataReader.
    using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
    {        
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
}
```

Or if you need to specify data types:

```
using CSVHelper;
..
..
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    // Do any configuration to `CsvReader` before creating CsvDataReader.
    using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
    {        
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        dt.Load(dr);
    }
}
```

(snippets taken from [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/data-table))